# How to get Image load time

Tags: javascript, html, browser, webp

I am working as back-end developer and I am new to html. Recently I am considering using webp instead of jpg for certain requests. Webp is definitely much smaller but I need data to show how much faster when I switch from jpg to webp in html.

I know I can see it from browsers' network info but that doesn't include the cost of rendering images, does it ? How should I do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The load time is the rendering time too if the image is actually displayed on the page. I have not seen tests that can show when the last pixel is visible in the browser so the load time is what to use

Comment: Thanks mplungjan. I thought that was only the cost of waiting for response from the server.